# Computing the volume of a cube

Tags: volume, finite-element-method

There are two ways one can compute the volume of a cube after deformation: a. either by dividing the cube into smaller tetrahedrons and then computing the before and after volume and b. to triangulate the faces of the cube and apply divergence theorem (with axis aligned flow) to compute the volume.

Can anyone help with the argument of why b is better way than a?